# Devise Saml Authenticatable Gem Error - AuthnRequest with AuthnContexts is not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, shibboleth

I'm using [devise_saml_authenticatable](https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable) gem to make the Ruby on Rails application acts as a **Service Provider(SP)** to allow users to authenticate using SAML SSO.

The **Idp** is a Shibboleth solution which uses `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password` as authn context.

However, I am stuck with the following error:

```
<Status>
  <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder">
    <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:RequestUnsupported" />
     </StatusCode>
     <StatusMessage> The AuthnRequest with AuthnContexts is not supported! 
     </StatusMessage>
</Status>
```

I tried all sorts of **authn_context** possible combination, but nothing seems to working.

It would be really helpful if you can provide any insight to resolve the error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's a responder code from the IdP that they are currently configured to *not* support Service Providers specifying the AuthnContext parameter within the SAML AuthnRequest.

Do you have `settings.authn_context = ""` specified in the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file? Or do you specify `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password`.

To say that Shibboleth uses that AuthnContext is a gross-overstatement. Shibboleth supports many context classes, including custom-defined ones for things like multi-factor authentication. `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password` is just one of many that is supported by Shibboleth. Which Authn flows are enabled by the IdP administrator is another story. Perhaps that is the only flow they have configured and is, hence, the default flow.

I would try sending the AuthnRequest with an empty AuthnContext, because it looks like this particular IdP has been configured to disable the ability of the SP to specify that.

In Shib IdP 3+ this can be done by specifying `p:disallowedFeatures-ref="SAML2.SSO.FEATURE_AUTHNCONTEXT"` on either the default relying party or the particular RelyingPartyOverride for your SP. You might ask the IdP administrator and ask if they specify that property on the `SAML2.SSO` bean?

Comment: Thanks @Kellen for the response. I have tried setting `settings.authn_context = ""` but had no luck.

Comment: Did you get the same message? That's an IDP-generated message. You might get some luck taking a look at what pops up in the idp-process.log if you can get it from the IDP admin.